# iOS 13 - Status of Bluetooth radio without instantiating a CBCentralManager

Tags: ios, bluetooth, ibeacon, ios13

My app uses iBeacon to monitor for beacons only (not range for them). The iBeacon protocol somewhat counterintuitively falls under the CoreLocation framework, not CoreBluetooth. Nonetheless, it needs the device's Bluetooth radio to be on in order to work. The Bluetooth radio for the device is toggled on/off from the Settings app (a separate setting from the one in the Control Center which can temporarily sever connections to peripherals).

Prior to iOS 13, to know whether the radio is on and therefore iBeacon will work, I would instantiate a CBCentralManager, then check the callback for a value of .poweredOn. But now, whenever a CBCentralManager is even instantiated, the OS displays a dialog "(app) Would Like To Use Bluetooth. Don't Allow/OK".  From a UX and also technical perspective, I do not need this dialog - I'm only trying to use iBeacon which shouldn't be subject to whatever safeguards this dialog is trying to enforce. To make matters worse, if I'm forced to use this dialog, if the radio is off and the user taps "OK", that action is powerless to turn the radio on, leaving the user confused as to why Bluetooth isn't working. This IMO is a bug, and I've submitted it to Apple, but that's an aside from the question.

The question is - **is there another way to get the radio status other than instantiating a CBCentralManager?** Or another approach I can take based on what I've described here?

Comment: It isn't a bug for the "OK" not to turn Bluetooth on - This is a permission dialog, not a radio control dialog.  It is only shown once.  What if, after granting, permission the user subsequently runs your app with Bluetooth off; This dialog isn't going to be shown again, so you need your own check and dialog as David suggests.  Also, from a UX point of view, consenting to Bluetooth access shouldn't imply turning Bluetooth back on.  If the dialog read "This app wants to turn Bluetooth on" or similar, then it would be a different story.

Comment: Well, at the very least, it's not a great design decision what they've done with coupling the instantiation of a CBCentralManager to always displaying this dialog. iBeacon monitoring/ranging doesn't need the permissions that can be granted in this dialog, yet it does need the info the CBCentralManager can provide.

Comment: The challenge they faced was they wanted a permission dialog to be shown in iOS 13 even for older apps because some apps were using Bluetooth for user location tracking without the user being aware. This meant they couldn't rely on a specific Bluetooth permission request from the app, and instead something that is already happening. The simplest is to trigger when the CBcentralManager is instantiated. For newer apps they can provide the new unauthorised status when an app is expecting status updates.  While I understand that it may not be great for your needs, it is what it is

Answer (score 1):

When initializing the `CBCentralManager`, you can provide the option `CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey` with the value `false` (it defaults to `true`, which causes the popup to appear).

```swift
let centralManager = CBCentralManager(
    delegate: self,
    queue: nil,
    options: [CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey: false]
)
```

Comment: In my testing (admittedly, objective C not Swift), this option doesn't seem to work anymore... (iOS 15.5)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your analysis is correct.  If bluetooth is off in settings you will never get beacon callbacks.  The only way to check if bluetooth is on is to use CoreBluetooth APIs that trigger the permission dialog on iOS 13.   I do not believe there is another way.

If you do obtain the bluetooth permission and find that the radio is off, you can pop a new dialog to tell the user bluetooth is off and direct them to turn it on in settings.  The OK button can link to settings, but your app may be rejected if you try and use a "private API" by linking directly to the bluetooth pane:

```
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Bluetooth must be on", message: "This app must have bluetooth turned on to detect when you are near a garage gate to open it.  Press OK to go to settings to turn on bluetooth.", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler:  {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in
            let settingsUrl = UIApplication.openSettingsURLString
            // the following URL is not allowed.  It caused my app to be rejected.                              
            // "prefs:root=BLUETOOTH"
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: settingsUrl)!)
        }))
        currentViewController.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```